# how can I make dataflow autoscale faster?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a naively parallel beam python job on dataflow. It spend close to 20 minutes with 1 cpu, then scales up to hundreds and finishes in another 20 minutes. Is there a way to make it auto-scale up in less time?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the workers the job needs to start, you can specify `num_workers` . The doc is here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/pipeline-options#resource_utilization

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, Dataflow [Horizontal Autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/horizontal-autoscaling#configure) should efficiently handle the job since it automatically determines the required number of workers to run it.

> Dataflow scales based on the parallelism of a pipeline. The parallelism of a pipeline is an estimate of the number of threads needed to most efficiently process data at any given time.

Phyton [Class AutoscalingAlgorithm](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/dataflow/latest/google.cloud.dataflow_v1beta3.types.AutoscalingAlgorithm) mentions the same logic if the value is set to AUTOSCALING_ALGORITHM_BASIC.

> AUTOSCALING_ALGORITHM_BASIC (2): Increase worker count over time to reduce job execution time.

In case you are not satisfied with it's performance, then you can explore the  manual way by turning off autoscaling (`--autoscaling_algorithm=NONE`) and set the number of your workers like what [XQ Hu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21289117/xq-hu) mentioned.